# Panda dataframe column conditional on another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import numpy as np
url="https://www.misoenergy.org/Library/Repository/Market%20Reports/20170811_da_bc.xls"

cnstxls = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
xl = pd.ExcelFile(cnstxls)
df = xl.parse("Sheet1",skiprows=3)
constr = df.iloc[:,1:7]
constr['Class'] = np.where(constr['Hour of Occurrence'] == (1,2,3,4,5,6), 'Offpeak', 'Onpeak')
sumsp=constr.groupby('Constraint_ID','Class',axis=0)['Shadow Price'].sum().sort_values(ascending=True)`
```

1) New column class is giving errors - says `TypeError: invalid type comparison`. How would I set this new column based on multiple hours? This works when I put only one hour (1 or 2 or 3...)

2) `TypeError: groupby() got multiple values for argument 'axis'`. 
I would like to `GROUPBY` using two columns. It works with one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
constr['Class'] = np.where(constr['Hour of Occurrence'].isin([1,2,3,4,5,6]),'Offpeak','Onpeak')

sumsp = constr.groupby(['Constraint_ID','Class'],axis=0)['Shadow Price'].sum().sort_values(ascending=True)

print(sumsp)
```

Output:

```
Constraint_ID  Class  
281292         Onpeak    -780.05
1049           Onpeak    -364.68
4636           Onpeak    -276.62
201082         Onpeak    -245.44
1607           Onpeak    -237.36
98333          Onpeak    -112.05
107318         Onpeak     -96.10
270366         Onpeak     -80.71
267644         Onpeak     -73.25
285770         Onpeak     -59.53
1049           Offpeak    -46.52
281292         Offpeak    -33.80
270888         Onpeak     -19.68
289484         Offpeak    -10.41
               Onpeak      -4.52
1607           Offpeak     -2.60
9712           Onpeak       0.84
268470         Onpeak       1.14
248010         Onpeak       1.48
287090         Onpeak       1.63
               Offpeak     11.78
188144         Offpeak     26.32
4862           Onpeak      28.03
285770         Offpeak     50.21
Name: Shadow Price, dtype: float64
```

## Edit `unstack` to pivot class:

```
sumsp.unstack('Class')
```

Output:

```
Class          Offpeak  Onpeak
Constraint_ID                 
1049            -46.52 -364.68
1607             -2.60 -237.36
4636               NaN -276.62
4862               NaN   28.03
9712               NaN    0.84
98333              NaN -112.05
107318             NaN  -96.10
188144           26.32     NaN
201082             NaN -245.44
248010             NaN    1.48
267644             NaN  -73.25
268470             NaN    1.14
270366             NaN  -80.71
270888             NaN  -19.68
281292          -33.80 -780.05
285770           50.21  -59.53
287090           11.78    1.63
289484          -10.41   -4.52
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. One follow up. How would I pivot this data by class, that is, onpeak and offpeak comes out as two separate columns?

Comment: @ShyamaSonti Added edit.  You need to `unstack('Class')`.

Comment: Scott - in the unstack above, I want to get the 'Constraint Name' for the Constraint_ID'. First constraint name is sufficient. You can see the constraint name in the constr df. Any help please.

Comment: You can simply replace 'Constraint_Id' with 'Constraint Name' in the first groupby where sumsp =... `sumsp = constr.groupby(['Constraint Name','Class'],axis=0)['Shadow Price'].sum().sort_values(ascending=True)`